# Get-ShardMapManager without Username and Password

Tags: database, azure, powershell, sharding

Is it possible to call `Get-ShardMapManager` when creating a new shard map manager without involving username and password (through hardcoding or storing the values in key vault)

Here is the code that I currently have in powershell

`$ShardMapManager = Get-ShardMapManager -Username $DbUsrId -Password $DbPwd`

can i use token or something like that? just whatever that is not involving username and password? thanks

Comment: This is more of a runtime strategy question. Where will the PowerShell be executing? Under what security context? Invoked by what trigger? What version of PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. From the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/blob/f6a3543293610181fccdde479273d7b6b43a9e21/Samples/PowerShell/ShardManagement/ShardManagement.psm1#L126) of `Get-ShardMapManager`, `UserName` and `Password` are all `Mandatory=$true`.

In this case, if you want to avoid using them just because of the security issue, you can use azure keyvault to store them via [`Set-AzKeyVaultSecret`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-5.5.0) as you mentioned. Retrieve them in the commands, then pass them to `Get-ShardMapManager`, just user/service principal that added to the [access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal) of the keyvault is able to get them(or has the `Key Vault Administrator` if you select [`Azure role-based access control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#data-plane-and-azure-rbac-preview) in `Access policies` blade of the keyvault).

Make sure you have installed `Az` powershell module, then use the command below.

```
Connect-AzAccount
$DbUsrId = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "keyvaultname" -Name "username" -AsPlainText
$DbPwd = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "keyvaultname" -Name "password" -AsPlainText
$ShardMapManager = Get-ShardMapManager -Username $DbUsrId -Password $DbPwd
```